# Terraform - Unimplemented AWS API services - SES CreateCustomVerificationEmailTemplate

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've recently started using Terraform and I love it.  However in migrating an application to use terraform I have encountered an AWS service that doesn't appear to be implemented using terraforms aws provider.

What does one do in such a situation?  Is there a way i can hack this in to my terraform code to call this api?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_CreateCustomVerificationEmailTemplate.html

I'm using the latest aws provider.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.5.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have old version of aws provider? Sadly you did not provided much info in your question about your setup.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the version of the provider i'm using @Marcin (the latest version)

Comment: You can always make an issue at https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws. If you want to "hack this", AWS TF provider is fully open sourced. So you can fork it and modify or contribute to mainstream branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possibility I could imagine is to run using local-exec and call the missing API manually.
E.g. you can use null_resource (https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/null_resource) and execute a bash script or aws cli directly.

Like mentioned before, search https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues for your issue, vote for it or create a new feature request.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently encountered a similar issue with missing configurations for `aws_cloudwatch_composite_alarm`. What I was missing was an alarm suppression. Yes, there was already an [issue for that][1].

I've used `local-exec`, but as it comes with many caveats, I considered expending the answer for others who struggle. Basically, it sounded easy: take the created composite resources and run AWS CLI through bash. However:

1. Many AWS commands are based on the HTTP PUT method, which means omitting a field clears it.
2. Same applies to the terraform client. When a value for a resource was set outside terraform, the next update clears it.
3. It's necessary to ensure the bash change is triggered whenever required (any change to the composite alarm).

So in my case, alarm suppression was removed with every update to an alarm.

```hcl
locals {
  # maintain a single source of alarms needing an update
  composite_alarms = [
    aws_cloudwatch_composite_alarm.cx-service_host_count,
    aws_cloudwatch_composite_alarm.cx-high-memory-utilization,
    aws_cloudwatch_composite_alarm.cx-high-cpu-utilization
  ] 
}

resource "null_resource" "update_composite_alarms" {
  for_each = tomap({
    for a in local.composite_alarms : "${a.alarm_name}" => a
  })

  # use a hash of complete resources intended for change, 
  # so that any change to the composite alarm will trigger 
  # a `null_resource` update
  triggers = {
    cx_alarm_hash = "${sha256(jsonencode(each.value))}" 
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOF 
    update_composite_alarm() {
        local alarm_name=$1

        # wait to make sure the alarm is created
        aws cloudwatch wait composite-alarm-exists --alarm-names $alarm_name --alarm-types CompositeAlarm 
 
        # pull the skeleton of AWS request 
        local skeleton=`aws cloudwatch put-composite-alarm --generate-cli-skeleton |  jq -c`

        # pull the existing alarm - to that no fields are removed
        # during update
        local existing_alarm=`aws cloudwatch describe-alarms --alarm-types CompositeAlarm --alarm-names $alarm_name --output json | jq -r '.CompositeAlarms[0]'`
        
        local merged_alarm_configuration=$(
            # existing alarm configuration
            echo "$existing_alarm" \
                # additional configuration not supported by terraform provider
                | jq ". += {\"ActionsSuppressor\": \"${aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.supressor.alarm_name}\"}" \
                | jq ". += {\"ActionsSuppressorWaitPeriod\": 60}" \
                | jq ". += {\"ActionsSuppressorExtensionPeriod\": 240}" \
                
                # remove all fields which are not present in the 
                # generated skeleton - for validation purposes
                | jq --argjson ref "$skeleton" 'with_entries(select(.key | in($ref)))'
            )

        # run the update
        aws cloudwatch put-composite-alarm --cli-input-json "$merged_alarm_configuration"
    }

    update_composite_alarm ${each.key}
    EOF

    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
  }
}
```

[1]: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/32251)